# Understanding principal angles

Tags: python, scipy, pytorch

I'm trying to understand [principle angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats) better by calculating them, and I found the [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.subspace_angles.html) has an easy function to do that.

Say I have 2 arrays:

```
from scipy.linalg import subspace_angles as sa
import torch

arr1 = torch.tensor([[1,2],[1.4,2.4]])
arr2 = torch.tensor([[2,3],[11,22]])
```

I can calculate it using:

```
sa(arr1,arr2)
>>> array([8.36970078e-08, 3.55122804e-08])
```

However, I don't quite understand the calculation. For example, why the following works?

```
arr1 = torch.tensor([[1,0,0,1,0,0], [0,1,0, 1,0,0]])
arr2 = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],[0,0,1]])
sa(arr1,arr2)
>>>array([1.57009246e-16, 0.00000000e+00])
```

And this one gives an error

```
arr1 = torch.tensor([[1,0,0,1,0,0], [0,1,0, 1,0,0], [0,1,0, 1,0,0]])
arr2 = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],[0,0,1]])
sa(arr1,arr2)
>>>ValueError: A and B must have the same number of rows, got 3 and 2
```

And this one gives a `0`

```
arr1 = torch.tensor([[1,9]])
arr2 = torch.tensor([[2,33]])
sa(arr1,arr2)
>>> 0
```

I may be wrong, but from what I'm seeing it seems like if I have a tensor of size `i`, I will get `i` principal angles.